# Нахождения остатка числа, выходящего за рамки целочисленных типов

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, типы-данных

Есть число, выходящее за диапазон `int64`, поэтому я храню его в строке, мне нужно поделить его на число в диапазоне `int64` и получить остаток, остаток тоже будет в пределах `int64`, как такое деление можно реализовать?

Comment: Ищите модули "длинной арифметики". Можно прямо по этому словосочетанию и искать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При сложении двух чисел остатки от деления (то, что называется "по модулю") складываются. При умножении остатки перемножаются - судите сами: пусть первое число при делении на d дает остаток 1, т.е. оно имеет вид = kd+r1, второе = nd+r2, при перемножении будет (...)*d + r1*r2

Так что вам просто надо делить на небольшие части, и начинать искать соответствующие остатки...

Пример приводить или идея и так понятна?

**Update**

Допустим, максимальный размер хранимого значения - 1000, а нам нужно найти остаток от деления 123456 на 21. Запишем как:

```
(12*100+34)*100+56
```

и заменим члены на их остатки (все члены уже маленькие):

```
(12*16+13)*16+14 => (192+13)*16+14 => (3+13)*16 + 14 => 256 + 14 => 4+14 => 18
```

Проверим...

```
123456 = 5878*21+18
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: Был бы вам благодарен за небольшой пример, пока не совсем понял насчет деления на части. Особенно если строка нечетной длины.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ. Код писать не буду - Pascal/Delphi работал давно, компилятора под рукой нет. Идея вам, думаю, и так понятна?..