# Поиск кратного числа в длинной арифметике

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, delphi, длинная-арифметика

Есть какое большое число(история умалчивает его максимальную длину, но ограничимся `10000` цифр), которое хранится по цифре в массиве. Есть какой-то делитель который меньше этого числа и не больше типа `integer`. Надо найти самое первое число, которое будет делиться нацело указанным делителем и будет больше загаданного числа, но это число не может быть больше по длине чем загаданное(допустим у `1234` верхний порог `9999`). Такое вообще можно какими-то оптимальными способами реализовать? Если есть пример программы, то язык реализации не принципиален, я ставлю цель понять суть метода.

Answer (score 4):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786773/195342) рассказывается, как получить остаток от деления большого и длинного числа на что-то в пределах типа :)

Находим этот остаток, вычитаем его их делителя, и получившуюся разность добавляем к этому большому числу. Добавляем, грубо говоря, в столбик, по цифре с переносом - это просто.

Собственно, вот и все.

**Update**

Вот примерно на С++, не самым эффективным способом (ибо по одной цифре):

```
char Num[] = "143226312356142387649161991124";
int  d     = 1434532;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << Num << endl;

    int rem = 0;
    for(char * c = Num; *c; ++c)
    {
        rem = (rem*10 + *c - '0')%d;
    }
    int add = d - rem;
    // Считаем, что переполнение Num при сложении не произойдет -
    // просто чтоб не заморачиваться новой более длинной строкой
    int carry = 0;
    for(char * n = Num + strlen(Num) - 1; carry || add ; --n)
    {
        int dig = (add%10 + carry); carry = 0;
        *n += dig;
        if (*n > '9') { *n -= 10; carry = 1; }
        add /= 10;
    }

    cout << Num << endl;

}
```

Comment: А переполнения с сотками и прочим не будет? И как вообще так разбить число?

Comment: Да как вам удобно, так и разбивайте. Переполнения? Ну, если делитель меньше половины целочисленного - то не будет. Возьмите для 32-битного делителя 64-битную арифметику, например. Если и число, и делитель слишком велики - ну, тогда надо думать о дополнительных мерах...

Answer (score 0):

Слишком длинно для комментария...
Задачу можно решить в 2 этапа.

---

Первый этап. Вычисление остатка

1. Обнуляем накопитель (формат int64).
2. Дописываем в строку нули слева так, чтобы её длина стала кратной 18.
3. Двигаясь по строке слева направо, переводим очередную 18-символьную подстроку в число формата int64.
4. Остатки по каждому из полученных чисел прибавляем к накопителю.
5. По окончанию цикла заменяем число в накопителе на остаток.

---

Второй этап. Добавление остатка.

1. Переводим правую 18-символьную подстроку в десятичное число и добавляем его к накопителю.
2. Остаток от деления содержимого накопителя на 10<sup>18</sup> записываем в правую подстроку.
3. Если число в накопителе больше или равно 10<sup>18</sup> (что вряд ли), производим перенос этой единицы справа налево по аналогии с пп. 1-3.